# How to display configurable color swatches in a custom product list?

Tags: php, magento

I have created a `phtml` file for listing some specific categories at home page. I have called this file at CMS home page via this code: `"{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/hometabs.phtml"}}"` and everything is working.

I want to display the color swatches on custom page after name.

In `list.phtml`, color swatches are displayed via this code from file `configurableswatches.xml` in layout folder:

```
    <product_list>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-list.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list.name.after">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_list.swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list.after">
            <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_media_js_list" name="configurableswatches.media.js.list" />
        </reference>
    </product_list>
```

My phtml code:

```
    <div name="tab_content" id="tab_content_1" class="tab_content active ">
    <?php   

        $categoryId = 8;    
        $collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
       ->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
       $_collectionSize=$collection->count();           
       if($collection->count()>0):              
      ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
    <?php $i=0; ?>
    <?php 
        $attributeOptions = array();
        foreach($collection as $pro): 
        $productAttributeOptions = $pro->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($pro);
        ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
      <ul id="add-strip-tab<?php echo $hotSellercount++; ?>">
     <?php endif ?> 

                    <li>
                        <?php if($pro->getHotProduct() == 3){ ?>
                            <div class="sohot"><span class="sohot-text">so hot right now</span></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <figure>
                             <a href="<?php echo $pro->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                 <img src="<?php echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($pro, 'small_image')->resize(272,272); ?>" alt="<?php  echo $pro->getName(); ?>">
                             </a>
                        </figure>
                        <h3 class="product-name"><?php  echo $pro->getName(); ?></h3>
    <div class="abc">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>  

            </div>          

                <?php if($pro->getSpecialPrice()){ ?>
                    <div class="price-box">                                            
                        <p class="old-price">
                            <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
                            <span class="price" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($pro->getPrice(),true,false); ?></span>
                        </p>                            
                        <p class="special-price">
                            <span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
                            <span class="price" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($pro->getSpecialPrice(),true,false); ?></span>   
                        </p>                
                    </div>
                    <?php } else {?>
                    <div class="price-box">
                        <p class="old-price">
                            <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
                            <span class="" ><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($coll->getPrice(),true,false); ?></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <?php }?>
            </li>   
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 ): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>     
        <?php endforeach; ?>

     <?php else: ?>
     <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
     <?php endif;  ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your phtml file code?

Comment: I have added my phtml code